# Rails cocoon: Nested fields disappear after I submit the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have the following three models and associations:

```
class ParentProduct < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :child_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child_products, allow_destroy: true
  has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
end

class ChildProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent_product
  has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
end

class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :parent_product, optional: true
 belongs_to :child_product, optional: true
 mount_uploader :image, AttachmentUploader
end
```

This in the controller:

```
def new
  @parent_product = ParentProduct.new
  8.times{ @parent_product.attachments.build }
end

def create
  @parent_product = ParentProduct.new(product_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @parent_product.save
      flash[:success] = "Product was successfully added."
      format.html { redirect_to product_index_path }
      format.json { render :new, status: :created, location: @parent_product }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @parent_product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def product_params
  params.require(:parent_product).permit(:name, :price, :color, :size, :description, :subcategory_id,
                                       attachments_attributes: [:id, :image, :parent_product_id, :child_product_id],
                                       child_products_attributes: [:price, :color, :size, :parent_product_id)
end
```

I use the following form in order to create a parent product and the attachments for this parent product. Also with the same form I can create many child products(along with the attachments for each child product) and associate them with this parent product:

```
<%= simple_form_for @parent_product, url: parent_product_path, method: :post, validate: true do |f| %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :attachments do |attachment| %>
    <%= render 'parent_products/attachment_fields', form: attachment  %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :child_products do |child_product| %>
    <%= render 'parent_products/child_product_fields', form: child_product %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="links float-right" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <%= link_to_add_association raw('<i class="far fa-plus-square"></i> Add a product variation'), 
    f, :child_products, form_name: 'form',
    wrap_object: Proc.new {|child| 8.times {child.attachments.build }; child }, 
    style: "color: grey; font-size: 14px;" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

As you can see above, I'm using this `wrap_object: Proc.new {|child| 8.times {child.attachments.build }; child }` for the  `child_products nested form`, in order to create 8 attachment fields when I click and add that nested form.

Inside the `child_products nested form` I have another nested form in order to create the attachments for the child product.

```
<%= form.simple_fields_for :attachments do |attachment| %>
  <%= render 'parent_products/attachment_fields', form: attachment  %>
<% end %>
```

The partial for the `attachment_fields` has only this input:

```
<%= form.input :image, label: false, as: :file, input_html: %>
```

The only issue is that when I submit the form and for some reason(validation error) the form gets rendered again, the 8 attachment fields disappear. Any idea on how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the source of your `ParentProductsController` class please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Fabian Winkler! I just added the `ParentProductsController` content to my initial question. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Not really sure if this is "real" code or just an example: did you add the `inverse_of` to your has_many/belongs_to relations? Because since rails 5 the `belongs_to` is required by default, and if you do not declare the `inverse_of` saving a nested form will not work. If that is not the validation error, I am assuming your question is: suppose I save a child_product with only 1 attachment, yet you always want to show 8, so you have to add 7 "empty" spots, is that the question?

Comment: Yes, this is the real code that I'm using. I aded the `inverse_of` to the has_many/belongs_to relations, but still the same thing is happening. This is what I did `belongs_to :child_product, optional: true, :inverse_of => :attachments has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy, :inverse_of => :child_product`

Comment: To answer your question I always have to show 8 attachment fields, but some times a user might save less then that. And this is how I handle it: I don't have validations inside the attachments model and I'm not using the `reject_if: :all_blank` for the empty fields. I use a `before_save` in order to find the empty data that is being submitted and `mark_for_destruction`. The validation errors are from the `ChildProduct` model `validates_presence_of :color, :size, :price`. But even if I delete the above `validates_presence_of` and submit the form, the 8 attachments fields still disappear.

Comment: This is the `before_save` method that I'm using inside the `ChildProduct` model in order to `mark_for_destruction` the empty data that is being submitted `child_attachments.each do |attachment| attachment.mark_for_destruction if attachment.image.blank?`

Comment: It seems a bit arbitrary to only allow 8 attachments, but that does not matter. Why not just keep empty attachments as a placeholder? (so not mark them for destruction). But anyway: your point is if the validation fails on the child-product, all the attachments are lost? Always? Which rails version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now see the problem! The attachments for your `child_products` are not permitted.

In your `product_params` you now have:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:parent_product).permit(:name, :price, :color, :size, :description, :subcategory_id,
                                       attachments_attributes: [:id, :image, :parent_product_id, :child_product_id],
                                       child_products_attributes: [:price, :color, :size, :parent_product_id)
end
```

and it should be (reformatted for clarity)

```
def product_params
  params.require(:parent_product).permit(
      :name, :price, :color, :size, :description, :subcategory_id,
      attachments_attributes: [:id, :image, :parent_product_id, :child_product_id],
      child_products_attributes: [
           :price, :color, :size, :parent_product_id, 
           attachments_attributes: [:id, :image, :parent_product_id, :child_product_id]
      ])
end
```

You should also see a warning in your `development.log` that the parameter(s) are blocked.